# iOS, Action after click into text block

Tags: ios, iphone

in this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bible/id282935706?mt=8 I found a nice feature that I want to learn to how it's was implemented.

In this app, when I click on a text block, it underline and show small icon in bottom left corner with few action.

Can you give me some advice how it was implemented or how I can do something similar?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `UITextField *textField` then set your view controller as the text field's delegate like so:

```
self.textField.delegate = self
```

Make sure you declare `self` to be a `UITextFieldDelegate` in the interface line:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then, implement the method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

In there you can run code to show any icons in the bottom left corner.